# POSTMAN Fiddler HTTP Error 401.2 Unauthorized Error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, fiddler, postman

I have created a WebAPI Project in Visual Studio with below security setting:

[image]

When I test this application from Chrome/IE, it prompts for User ID/Password and show the output.   However when I try to test the same endpoint from Fiddler/POSTMAN, it gives me 401.2 error.  Here is the error details:

> HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
>   You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.
>
> Detailed Error Information:
>
> Module    IIS Web Core
>
> Notification    AuthenticateRequest
>
> Handler    ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
>
> Error Code    0x80070005
>
> Requested URL    http://localhost:888/api/Security
>
> Physical Path    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebServices\api\Security
>
> Logon Method    Not yet determined
>
> Logon User    Not yet determined

I have tried giving the Authorization Header in Fiddler, but no luck. In Postman, I selected the Authorization Type from None to Basic Auth, and provided the username and password.  This also doesn't help.

Does anyone know or can hint me whats going wrong with Fiddler/Postman?